# Can every curve be represented as an equation?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

If I plot some points randomly on the graph and then join them, can that curve be represented as a polynomial? I know that a straight line can be expressed algebraically as a linear equation, and quadratic equation as a parabola, but can you express a smooth curve which is made by joining some random points on the graph algebraically ?

Comment: Yes, you can, by using min and max functions (or alternatively, absolute values). (Assuming zigzag means a union of line segments)

Comment: Maybe you should remove the tag algebraic geometry

Comment: why is everyone downvoting this post of a new user instead of telling the user what to do. That is not welcoming, please remove the downvotes and only place them if the user turns unwilling to incorporate the suggested and necessary changes.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking about plotting a curve yourself, or just choosing the points. As the other answer shows, if you select any number of points, then an algebraic (polynomial) curve can pass through them, but if a curve is randomly drawn, then it is possible that it cannot be represented by an algebraic equation.

Comment: @DevanshBhardwaj, thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: It is not needed to thank for the answer, moreover it should not be said. That is just a part of stackexchange :)

Comment: The term "interpolation" is usually applied to fitting a curve to a set of isolated function values.  See the Wikipedia article on [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation).  The fitting can be done in more than one way unless you further described how the curve is to be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are functions like [trigonometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry) and [logarithmic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) functions which cannot be represented as polynomials, yet they can be graphed:

[image]

[image]
So it is not possible for every graph to represent a polynomial. However, these functions can be Approximated by [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to any desired degree of accuracy.

To illustrate it by an example, we may take the parabolic graph of $x^2$.

[image]
Now if one reflects the part of the graph to the left of y axis along the x axis, one roughly gets such a graph:
[image]
This graph is given by $x^2$ for $x>0$ and $-x^2$ for $x<0$, but it cannot be represented as a polynomial as the polynomial should be $x^2$ for x greater than zero and $-x^2$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

One may find a polynomial that passes through a given set of data points using the [Newton interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial).

The polynomial is given by

$$f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_in_i(x) \; \text{where} \; n_i(x)=\prod_{j = 0}^{i−1}(x−x_j) \; \text{and} \; a_i = [y_0, ..., y_i]$$

$[y_0, ..., y_i]$ is notation for [divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences).

You may see an application of this approach for a specific case [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2GPM.png) (pasted below).

> We can use the [Newton interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial) to get
>
> $$f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^n a_in_i(x) \; \text{where} \; n_i(x)=\prod_{j = 0}^{i−1}(x−x_j)$$
>
> We can now calculate the divided differences as follows
>
> $$a_0 = y_0 = -6.13$$
>
> $$a_1 = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0} = \frac{-3.61 + 6.13}{-0.32 + 9.17} = \frac{84}{295}$$
>
> $$a_2 = \frac{\frac{y_2 - y_1}{x_2 - x_1} - a_1}{x_2 - x_0} =
>  \frac{\frac{-5.6 + 3.61}{4 + 0.32} - \frac{84}{295}}{4 + 9.17} = \frac{-474965}{8391924}$$
>
> $$...$$
>
> The resulting polynomial is
>
> $$f(x) \approx
> 4.90547\times10^{-6}x^{6}-0.000246778x^{5}+0.00296915x^{4}+0.0154116x^{3}-0.323696x^{2}+0.380018x-3.45477$$
>
> [image]